# Firebase Functions Emulator is blocking the same port he tries to use (EADDRINUSE)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

After I start firebase functions emulator after first try I get (regularly) the same error

```
  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-api"
>  node:events:368
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>  
>  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3232
>      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1334:16)
>      at listenInCluster (node:net:1382:12)
>      at Server.listen (node:net:1469:7)
>      at Function.listen (/Users/userhere/Developer/project/functions/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Function/Developer/project/functions/index.js:33:5)
>      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
>      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>  Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
>      at emitErrorNT (node:net:1361:8)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
>    code: 'EADDRINUSE',
>    errno: -48,
>    syscall: 'listen',
>    address: '::',
>    port: 3232
>  }
```

Every single time. So I checked what is the origin of that process and, yup, you guessed it:

`cwd /Users/user/Developer/project/functions`

Why is functions emulator blocking his own calls? And how to prevent it?

The current temp solution is that I have to find the PID of the process, kill it and then it all works, but I don't want it to be like that. I want it to work out of the box, like normal proper working software.

For ppl having similar problems here is the temporary solution:

- use `sudo lsof -i :3232` (sudo might not be needed) to get PID
- and then `kill -9 {PID-here}`

Comment: Typically this happens when the emulator is already running. What command are you using to start the emulator? Did you attempt to shut down the already-running emulator from the previous invocation? There is an option to specify specific emulators to launch, such as `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` which avoids duplicating the functions emulator process.

Comment: I found I have app.listen(3232) in my index file. Removed it and since then it just works. Strange

Comment: @jeand'arme Can you post your answer. So, it might be helpful to other community members.

Comment: Posted @SandeepVokkareni

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true})
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')()
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')

const admin = require('./initFirebaseAdmin')
admin.initAdmin()
const { validateFirebaseIdToken } = require('./middleware/validateFirebaseUser')
const shouldValidateFirebaseIdToken = (fn) => {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path === '/zkzp/webhook' || req.path === '/zkzp/all' ) {
        next();
    } else {
        fn(req, res, next);
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors)
app.use(cookieParser)
app.use(shouldValidateFirebaseIdToken(validateFirebaseIdToken))

app.use(morgan('dev'))

// app.listen(3232) <- this was generating error (double-launch?)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

I removed `app.listen(3232)` and it resolved the problem. Not sure how even it got there in the first place.